# Enum in realstudio

Tags: realbasic, realstudio

Please, tell me - how to create an enum in RealStudio( I'm pretty new in this area ).
I want to create enum in the global scope for application, and can't find tutorial how to do this(((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a module and go to its Code Editor.  From the Project menu, select the Add submenu, then choose Enum.  Alternatively you can use the toolbar but I don't believe the Add Enum button is shown by default so you'll have to customize the toolbar to see it.

Comment: Thanks! I got answer [here](http://forums.realsoftware.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=43121) some time ago, but can't post it, because low reputation.